# Polymer - Firebase : iterar sobre datos de Firebase

Tags: polymer

Buen dia, tengo en firebase estos datos: [image: Datos de Firebase]

Bajo cada año_mes esta el key que es el ID de cada usuario que se ha registrado en ese mes año y lo que quiero hacer es en un componente "padre" sacar un listado de todos los usuarios y después en el componente hijo saber si ese usuario esta registrado en ese año_mes, sin embargo no consigo hacerlo :( tengo esto en el componente padre:

`<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{usuarios}}" as="usuario">

            <admin-consulta-pagos-item usuario="{{usuario}}" yearmes="{{yearmes}}" id="consultaspagos"></admin-consulta-pagos-item>
        </template>`

y en componente hijo tengo la propiedad : pagado que es Boolean y solo la quiero para bindearla a el check :(

```
consultar: function () {
            that = this;
            var usuariocreado = this.fbref('/yearmes/' + this.yearmes + '/' + this.usuario.$key);
            usuariocreado.once('value')
            .then(function (snapshot) {
                var a = snapshot.exists();
                console.log('existe en BD: ' + a);
                if (a) {
                    console.log('El usuario PAGO: ' + a)
                    that.pagado = true;
                } else {
                    that.pagado = false;
                }
            });
        },
```

Lo extraño es que el console.log que tengo ahi si me funciona perfecto y me dice si esta el registro o no, pero la propiedad pagado no se afecta correctamente :( solo la ultima , quizas no lo estoy pensando bien o algo no estoy considerando ¿alguien puede sugerirme algo para hacer esto?

Aqui el ejemplo de la pantalla de la app donde en ese mes estan los tres y solo marca el ultimo :(

[image: Ejemplo de la pantalla]

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes la línea:

```
that = this;
```

Sin la palabra "var". De ese modo, se genera una variable global "that" y su valor se machaca siempre con la última asignación. Por eso solo se te activa el valor en la última posición y no en todas las otras.

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Muchas gracias :( era una tonteria y no encontraba el problema.